# How to CREATE an OUTPUT JAVA PACKAGE from source code?

Tags: java, file, directory, package, output

I'm trying to:

- Create strings, in which I write Java code; **Ok**
- Put these Strings(Java classes) in some output .java file; **Ok**

**Problem**:

- In Java I can create a standard Directory (File.mkdir() etc.) in which i can put my .java file, but I can't find a way to create a PACKAGE DIRECTORY, that's my goal.

I want to transform this:

```
file=new File("path_specification");
file.mkdir();
```

to make a Java package.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You seem to be confusing compiling with running.  You do not write code to create packages;  you create the directories before compiling, and place your .java files in those directories using your computer or IDE, not with code.  The `package` directive at the start of each .java file determines what package the class is in.

Comment: If i create a directory in a .java file, the i can create text file in my code, and the i can put this text files in the directory. When i  output these text files, i give them .java extension. In this way, i create a directory, some .java files,  and finally i put those .java files in that directory. My goal is to create a package, instead of a standard folder. I solved putting my directory in the source root of the project, so automatically my directory is created as a package. P.s: I use Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A java package IS a directory. If you're using an ide, you can create the directory under the sources root with its .java file. And then you can compile it.

But be aware, however, trying to create a package in the .jar you are running can be impossible.

The only way to create a package in the .jar you are running is decompressing it, and then decompiling it to a .java file and then copy the package (aka directory with a .java file)

Comment: I solved putting my directory in the source folder of the java project ( I'm using Eclipse). In this way the directory is automatically created like a package. Thanks!